# How to rename AWS Athena columns with parquet file source?

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

I have data loaded in my S3 bucket folder as multiple parquet files.
After loading them into Athena I can query the data successfully.

**What are the ways to rename the Athena table columns for parquet file source and still be able to see the data under renamed column after querying?**

Note: checked with edit schema option, column is getting renamed but after querying you will not see data under that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is as far as I know no way to create a table with different names for the columns than what they are called in the files. The table can have fewer or extra columns, but only the names that are the same as in the files will be queryable.

You can, however, create a view with other names, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW a_view AS
SELECT
  a AS b,
  b AS c
FROM the_table
```

Comment: Since writing this I have learned about this: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/athena/latest/ug/handling-schema-updates-chapter.html#parquet-read-by-name – you can switch a Parquet based table from mapping columns by name to mapping them by index. When mapping by index the names of the columns of the table can be different from the columns in the files, they just have to appear in the same order.