# How to rename a column when creating an external table in Athena based on Parquet files in S3?

Tags: hive, parquet, amazon-athena

Does anybody know how to rename a column when creating an external table in Athena based on Parquet files in S3?

The Parquet files I'm trying to load have both a column named export_date as well as an export_date partition in the s3 structure.
An example file path is: `'s3://bucket_x/path/to/data/export_date=2020-08-01/platform=platform_a'`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `user_john_doe.new_table`(
  `column_1` string,
  `export_date` DATE,
  `column_3` DATE,
  `column_4` bigint,
  `column_5` string)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `export_date` string,
  `platform` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
LOCATION
  's3://bucket_x/path/to/data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'parquet.compression'='GZIP')
;
```

So what I would like to do, is to rename the export_date column to export_date_exp.  The AWS documentation indicates that:

> To make Parquet read by index, which will allow you to rename
> columns, you must create a table with parquet.column.index.access
> SerDe property set to true.

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/athena/latest/ug/handling-schema-updates-chapter.html#parquet-read-by-name

But the following code does not load any data in the export_date_exp column:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `user_john_doe.new_table`(
  `column_1` string,
  `export_date_exp` DATE,
  `column_3` DATE,
  `column_4` bigint,
  `column_5` string)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `export_date` string,
  `platform` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'parquet.column.index.access'='true')
LOCATION
  's3://bucket_x/path/to/data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'parquet.compression'='GZIP')
;
```

This question has been asked already, but did not receive an answer:

[How to rename AWS Athena columns with parquet file source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558973/how-to-rename-aws-athena-columns-with-parquet-file-source)

I am asking again because the documentation explicitly says it is possible.

As a side note: in my particular use case I can just not load the export_date column, as I've learned that reading Parquet by name does not require you to load every column.  In my case I don't need the export_date column, so this avoids the conflict with the partition name.

Comment: But don't you then already have the answer in your side note? If you don't specifiy `export_date` as a column Athena shouldn't read the column right?

Comment: I tested it and was able to rename a column, however I then had issues with the column order. Did you check that the underlying parquet files have the all the exact same order of column & no additional columns?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis 
In this case I am able to leave out the column, and load the data.  I think this is a workaround rather than a solution.  In most instances I would not be able to drop an entire column.  

   I would be curious to see the code you used to get it to work.  Yes, the underlying parquet files have the columns in the same order.

Comment: I just used `SHOW CREATE TABLE ` to show an existing table (also based on parquet), renamed a column and added the serdeproperties value. In your case you always see `NULL` ? If all columns after the specific columns are still correctly filled and have values it might be just the truth?

For deeper analysis I would recommend to download one parquet file and inspect it with a tool like [bigdata-file-viewer](https://github.com/Eugene-Mark/bigdata-file-viewer) to investigate the file and check if the column isn't empty.